# ACF and PACF graphs - MA, AR, ARMA, ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

The data are for areas.

How would I interpret these ACF and PACF graphs, and what model could I use?

[image: 1]

To me, this is a non-stationary series and therefore an ARIMA would be suitable, but I don't know which parameters to choose. It would be nice if someone could explain, I'm struggling with these new notions. Thanks.

Comment: I see no clear signs of nonstationarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an AR(1) process: gradually decaying ACF and a sharp cutoff in PACF after lag 1. While the ACF of AR(1) should not become negative at distant langs, this is not uncommon in small and medium samples, or even ones as large as 1000 observations - check out the following simulation:

```r
T=1000; 
set.seed(0); eps=rnorm(T); 
x=rep(NA,T); x[1]=eps[1]; 
for(t in 2:T) x[t]=0.8*x[t-1]+eps[t]; 
acf(x); 
pacf(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought that the ACF must be positive for any lag because this model assumes that previous observations have a positive influence on current observations. Therefore, I don't understand why the AR(1) model would be appropriate?

Comment: @weldon, good point, I will edit my answer.